# get latitude and longitude of my location when internet is disable in flutter

Tags: flutter

How can I get current location updates when the internet is disabled on mobile in flutter? I have used the geolocator package to get latitude and longitude of the current location.

Comment: Lat/Lng is not dependent directly on Internet connectivity. Have you tried anything? Please share if you are having any specific problems, error logs etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geolocator does not need internet enabled on mobile.

You can track position changes listening this stream Geolocator().getPositionStream()

https://pub.dev/documentation/geolocator/latest/geolocator/Geolocator/getPositionStream.html